# How do I use the FileUploadDialogHandler in watin to access the file upload dialog

Tags: c#, watin

I'm using IE8 with watin and am trying to test uploading a file via my webpage. I can't simply set the upload file using the set method like

ie.FileUpload(Find.ById("someId")).Set("C:/Desktop/image.jpg");

because the upload textarea is not writeable in IE8, so I have to use the FileUploadDialogHandler but I can't find any examples of how to do this.

I have found and used examples of the ConfirmDialogHandler successfully, but I can't seem to figure out how to use the FileUploadDialogHandler.

Any examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks OK. You don't have to use `FileUploadDialogHandler`. It is used internally when you call `Set` method.

Comment: But the textbox in the upload control is not writeable, so when I make the call the the Set method nothing happens in the browser and then when I try to do the upload I get a file does not exist error, which is the same as what happens when I do it manually. I can't enter any text without getting the upload dialog to popup first, and I can't figure out how to interact with the upload popup.

Comment: It's not about textbox. When you call `Set` WatiN would normally open a dialog and type filename in it using `FileUploadDialogHandler`. My guess is you have to add your site to trusted or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for you help with this. I added my site to trusted sites and now it works :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
FileUploadDialogHandler fileupload = new FileUploadDialogHandler("filename.xls");
using (new UseDialogOnce(ie.DialogWatcher, fileupload ))
{
   //code to intiate the file upload, like button.Click()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The dialog box was opening, but the filepath was not written. Dialog box was remained opened.
I found a by pass. Before using .Set function use the .Click function.

Something like that :

**ie.FileUpload(Find.ById("someId")).Click();
ie.FileUpload(Find.ById("someId")).Set("C:/Desktop/image.jpg");**